# How to iterate through an array of arrays of ojects in JSON?

Tags: java, arrays, json

It's been awhile since i programmed in java.

This is the first time I manipulate a JSON file. I know the logic, but I can't figure out how to manipulate it... here is an example:

```js
{ "a": [ 
      ["1","2"],["3","4"],
        [ ["5","6"],["7","8"] ],
        ["9","10"],
       ],
       "b":["11","12","13"]
}
```

First I get the 'a', then I iterate though it , but insite the 'a' I have an array of arrays. So question is: how to manipulate it in java?

this is my pseudocode:

```html
parse the JSON file

get(a) then
   loop in a
     loop in a[1]
      ...
     end loop a[1]
   end loop a
get(b) then
   loop in b
    ...
   end loop b
   
end program
```